# Image Slideshow in HTML

Tags: html, slider, slideshow, photo, slide

I am trying to make photo slide using links instead of photos saved on my computer.
There are 19 photos and the photo links only differ by their last digit:
eg,

1. Photo number one has link of "://www.g.com/photo0**1**.jpg"
2. Photo number two with link of "://www.g.com/photo0**2**.jpg"

I've been working on this code, but when I want to move to the next picture, nothing changes and when I want to click previous button, the main image disappears.

```
<body>
<div class = "main">
  <button id = "prev" class = "bot" onclick = "prev()"><</button>
  <img class = "imgSub" src = "https://www.takushoku-u.ac.jp/summary/images/summary_successive-chancellor_img_01.jpg" alt = "">
  <button id = "next" class = "bot" onclick = "next()">></button>
</div>
<script>
  var count;
  let mainElement = document.querySelector("div.main>.imgSub");
  let URL = "https://www.takushoku-u.ac.jp/summary/images/summary_successive-chancellor_img_";

  function next() {
    if (count < 19) {
      if (count < 10) {
        count++;
        URL = URL + "0" + count + ".jpg";
      } else {
        count++;
        URL = URL + count + ".jpg";
      }
    } else {
      count = 1;
      URL = URL + "0" + count + ".jpg";
    }
    mainElement.setAttribute('src', URL);
  }

  function prev() {
    if (count > 1) {
      if (count < 10) {
        count--;
        URL = URL + "0" + count + ".jpg";
      } else {
        count--;
        URL = URL + count + ".jpg";
      }
    } else if (count == 1){
      count = 19;
      URL = URL + count + ".jpg";
    } else {
      URL = URL + "01.jpg";
    }
    mainElement.setAttribute('src', URL);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <button id="prev" class="bot" onclick="prev()"><</button>
        <img id="imgSub" src="https://www.takushoku-u.ac.jp/summary/images/summary_successive-chancellor_img_01.jpg" alt="">
        <button id="next" class="bot" onclick="next()">></button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var count = 1;
        let mainElement = document.querySelector("div.main>.imgSub");
        let URL = "https://www.takushoku-u.ac.jp/summary/images/summary_successive-chancellor_img_";

        function next() {

            if (count < 19) {
                if (count < 10) {
                    count++;
                    x = URL + "0" + count + ".jpg"

                } else {
                    count++;
                    x = URL + count + ".jpg"
                }
            } else {
                count = 1;
                x = URL + "0" + count + ".jpg";
            }
            document.getElementById("imgSub").src = x;
        }

        function prev() {
            if (count > 1) {
                if (count < 10) {
                    count--;
                    x = URL + "0" + count + ".jpg"
                } else {
                    count--;
                    x = URL + count + ".jpg"
                }
            } else if (count == 1) {
                count = 19;
                x = URL + count + ".jpg";
            } else {
                x = URL + "01.jpg";
            }
            document.getElementById("imgSub").src = x;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't know if it is the correct way but it works, what you have asked for.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I tried fixing it, but maybe my ifs are wrong. I've been working on this for 3 days now, starting to think my computer is the broken one...

Comment: just change the variables as I have given,  it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easy and understandable for you too if you use bootstrap for image sliding.
Even if you don't have enough knowledge on it you can simply visit getbootstrap.com and from there you can copy the basic boiler plate of bootstrap into your html file and the required boiler plate for image carousel.